# How to insert multiple values in table using procedure in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, procedure

On running the following code I'm getting this as output:

> OUTPUT:- ORA-00001: unique constraint (KART.SYS_C007206) violated

I think I'm inserting  batch of values at a time in database. Maybe that's why it's not working.

```
      <!--  declare
      Enter_the_size_of_array int;
      id int;
      name varchar(30);
      age int
      c int;


      procedure s(a in out int , b in out varchar2,c in out int) is 
                begin 
                insert into table1 values(a,b,c);
                end;

      begin
      c:=1;
      Enter_the_size_of_array:= :Enter_the_size_of_array;


      loop 
                id:= :id;
                name:= :name;
                age:= :age;
                s(id,name,age);
                c:=c+1;
      exit when (c=Enter_the_size_of_array);
      end loop;

      end;
      / -->
```

Comment: Run this query. `SELECT
    table_name,
    column_name
FROM
    all_cons_columns
WHERE
    constraint_name = 'SYS_C007206';`  and tell me what you get.

Comment: i dint get your query

my table_name  is Table1
and 
column_names are Id,Name,Age

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ID is a unique key field. every time you have enter the same value for ID. it throws unique key constraint exception.

Comment: ok...thanks :)
But then how will i get user value without using loop? ...
i want to enter values .... lets say 4 values, 4 different values ...But its only entering the same value again and again

Comment: you can use a table type to store your set of values in a collection . and iterate through the collection while inserting it. 2nd method is if you are getting these data from a table then put the query into a cursor and loop through cursor

Answer (score 1):

Kumar, it looks like in every iteration of the loop, ID (and all of the other values) stay the same. Its more than likely that you have a constraint on one or more columns (such as a primary key on ID) and you're just trying to insert the same values over and over again.